# Gnome / GTK: Increase floating dock-widget "resize border" width?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-3

I am developing an app using Qt 5.5

I have a main window with a dock, and a dockable window which can be dragged out/popped out, floating in its own separate window. (`QDockWidget`)

The resize border width of the main window is perfectly adequate, so resizing the main window using the mouse is very easy.

### Resize margin width of main window (ie: when docked):

The space within the red border here represents the area where the mouse cursor changes to a resize cursor.

[image]

### Resize margin width of undocked window (ie: when hovering):

When I pop out my docked window (`QDockWidget`), so that it's now floating, the resize border width drops down to a single pixel

[image]

As such, it is almost impossible to resize a floating dock window.

I am running [Ubuntu Gnome 14.04](https://ubuntugnome.org/), so using Gnome 3 with (I think?) [Adwaita](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/06/13/a-new-default-theme-for-gtk/) theme.

I have tested this on default Ubuntu 14.04, so using Unity, and this is not an issue there (the resize border width is several pixels, so much easier to "find" with the mouse)

### Question:

How can I configure Gnome 3 / Adwaita to increase this border width?

Comment: I'm pretty sure when it's hovering the resizing is handled by the window manager.

Comment: Is there no way to override it?